# Is __name__ '__main__' when you run a Python script with a cronjob?

Tags: python, linux, cron

Is `__name__ == '__main__'` when you run a Python script with a cronjob?

Comment: Did you try checking for yourself?

Comment: @Griwes, did you even tried to read that page fully?

Answer (score 2):

If it is the entry point to a python process, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, as long you don't import it, it is `'__main__'`.